# How do I get an xml element by tag name?

Tags: .net, xml

This is an XML file I'm loading:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Table xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <child1>
    <child2></child2>
  </child1>
</Table>
```

I'm trying to get the element `<child2>`.

I'm using the following code:

```
var xroot = XElement.Load(filename);
var el = xroot.Element("Table");
```

The second line always returns `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the line `var el = xroot.Element("Table");`.

The `var xroot` holds the `<Table>` element (since this is the XML document's root element).

---

Based on your comment, this code works for me:

```
var xroot = XElement.Load(filename);
var el = xroot.Element("child1").Element("child2");
```

or alternatively, to get all "child2" nodes in the document:

```
var xroot = XElement.Load(filename);
var el = xroot.Element("child1").Element("child2");
foreach (XElement child2 in xroot.Descendants("child2"))
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... that doesn't seem to work either. Now I'm doing xroot.Element("child1") and it can't find the first element in `<Table>`. Which looks like: `<Table><child1><child2></child2></child1></Table>` I actually want the text content from `child2`. Ughh why does everything take forever with .NET.

Comment: @pixelmike `why does everything take forever with .NET.`   Because you fall into the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) trap. `xroot.Descendants("child2")`

Answer (score 1):

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load('yourXmlFile'); // or xmlDoc.LoadXml('your xml');
var mainXmlNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement; // this now holds information about your 'table' node
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. The other XML class has terrible documentation.

Comment: @pixelmike then please mark this as accepted answer so it will be easier for other people with the same problem to find the answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i see 1 empty element (Table) with 2 attributes in your example, right?

Seems correct that the first (and only element) "Table" is null, has no text content.